# the maximun time when Run Background Task with TimeTrigger

Tags: uwp, background-task

I call function taskBuilder.Register failed with exception . 
  Is the timetrigger limition is less than two month?

source code :

```
private const int TWO_MONTHS = **60 * 24 * 60**;
void reg_bgtask()
{
    var taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    IBackgroundTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger(TWO_MONTHS, true)       
    taskBuilder.Name = taskInfo[0];
    taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskInfo[1];
    taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
    taskBuilder.Register();
}
```

Exception:
  <   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register()

Comment: In my test, the max value that the TimeTrigger will accept is 30 days. But I have another question, why you need to set such a long time for your background task? And what you want to do in the background task?

Comment: Send an important notice an important notice after two/four/six months with a toast.

Comment: The time interval might too long and this is not what the background design for. If the app could always run in a device, is it acceptable to create a timer to check the date every day? Then you could send the toast on a particular day.